# How to wrap elements in Python3?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

There's a xml file like this:

```
<body>
            <part>verb</part>
            love
            <meaning>
                <num>1.</num>
            </meaning>
             like
</body>
```

I like to wrap contents after the first child and its tail of body node with `<text>...</text>`. That is,

```
<body>
            <part>verb</part>
            love
            <text>    
                <meaning>
                    <num>1.</num>
                </meaning>
                like
            </text>
</body>
```

I tried this, but I don't know next.

```
     import lxml.etree as ET
     xml = '''\    <body>
            <part>verb</part>
            love
            <meaning>
                <num>1.</num>
            </meaning>
             like
      </body>'''
      body = ET.fromstring(xml)  
      body.insert(2, text)
```

Comment: Your xml seems not valid: `<num>1.</mean_no>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from where you got:

```
body = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

now we need locate the element `meaning`, you can do it with xPath or `_Element.find`, or just  use hard coded index, in this case BTW, it is `1`, not `2`. I'm using `find` here:

```
meaning = find('meaning')
```

now we make a `<text>`and add it as a sibling of `<meaning>`:

```
text = body.makeelement('text')
meaning.addprevious(text)
```

in the end move `<meaning>` into `<text>`:

```
text.append(meaning)
```

note that the tailing text is also moved, and `append` will actually move the node.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

xml = """<body>
           <part>verb</part>
           love
                <meaning>
                    <num>1.</num>
                </meaning>
                like
</body>"""

body = etree.fromstring(xml)
rest = body[1:] # all children after the first
del body[1:]
text_el = body.makeelement('text', {})
text_el.extend(rest)
body.append(text_el)
print(etree.tostring(body, encoding=str))
```

#### Output

```xml
<body>
            <part>verb</part>
            love
                <text><meaning>
                    <num>1.</num>
                </meaning>
                like
</text></body>
```